# How to export or create MATHML from MS word 2010?

Tags: ms-word, office-2010, word-2010

I have mathematical expressions in word document. Is it possible to export data as MATHML format?

For example below formula existed in a word as a mathematical expression.

[image]

Above expression should represent as below MATHML code.

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"> 
<mrow> 
<mi>x</mi> 
<mo>=</mo> 
<mfrac> 
<mrow> 
<mo>&#x2212;</mo> 
<mi>b</mi> 
<mo>&#xB1;</mo> 
<msqrt> 
<mrow> 
<msup> 
<mi>b</mi> 
<mn>2</mn> 
</msup> 
<mo>&#x2212;</mo> 
<mn>4</mn> 
<mi>a</mi> 
<mi>c</mi> 
</mrow> 
</msqrt> 
</mrow> 
<mrow> 
<mn>2</mn> 
<mi>a</mi> 
</mrow> 
</mfrac>
```

I am able to paste the above example MATHML into word and it will create a graphic. But I am unable create MATHML from existing graphic (in MS Word).

Thank you for your help

Comment: See this other answer; it contains an example conversion from OpenXML to MathML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759100/how-to-parse-mathml-in-output-of-wordopenxml

Answer (score 0):

Office includes omml2mml.xsl; you can Google that for more info.

Comment: I just did. This useless answer is the #1 result on google.

Comment: Thanks to your constructive comment (ahem...), I noticed the stylesheet name was wrong and have fixed that in the answer.  Google now yields results such as http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murrays/archive/2008/07/28/improved-mathml-support-in-word-2007.aspx