# Reading equations & formula from Word (Docx)

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx, mathml

We have a word/docx file which has equations. Using POI's XWPFWordExtractor.getText doesn't read the equations.

My questions are:

1. What/how are these equations represented as?
2. How do I read them (I want to eventually display them on an HTML - as MathML??)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equation in a docx file is representation using omml [m:oMathPara](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/SharedML/oMathPara.html)/[m:oMath](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/SharedML/oMath.html):

```
  <m:oMathPara xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math">
    <m:oMath>
```

I don't know about POI, but in docx4j, elements in that namespace are represented using JAXB generated objects in [org.docx4j.math](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/math)

I'd tackle your second question by marshalling the m:oMathPara/m:oMath, then transforming via [omml2mathml.xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24790229/1031689)  See further Murray Sargent's blog (for example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murrays/archive/2007/04/15/creating-math-web-documents-using-word-2007.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murrays/archive/2008/07/28/improved-mathml-support-in-word-2007.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Will check out docx4j.